# Need Jquery Regex for validating alphanumeric space and following characters [],./\

Tags: jquery, validation

I want Jquery regex for validating alphanumeric, spaces and following characters [],./\

Can anyone please help me quickly, I do not know much about regex escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your regex.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.,[\]/\\ ]+$
```

Validate it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/Ey0MA0/2).

Comment: Thank you Mr. Amit, I understood the above expression with help of link!!, Once again thank you for saving my time.